# Calculate time difference in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

We have two columns in SQL. one is `total_work_time` & next is `total_exeption_time` & both column data type is varchar

`total_work_time` value is 07:15:00

`total_exeption_time` value is 01:15:00

So I need to subtract `total_work_time` - `total_exeption_time` and the result will be 06:00:00.

I have tried with `concat(DATEDIFF(HOUR,total_exeption_time,total_work_time),':',  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,total_exeption_time,total_work_time))`

But the result is 6:360. from this, 360 is the problem, it taken total minutes. I need the result structure like  `06:00:00`. How to fix this issue using SQL Server.

Comment: What datatype are your columns?

Comment: datatype  is varchar

Comment: Why are you storing a time value in a varchar instead of a time datatype?

Comment: It is calculation from different cte and i can't change data type, because it is already fixed by client. can i do time calculation using varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be storing time values in a `TIME` datatype - using the correct datatype is not only a best practice but will reduce the problems you face in future.

You can convert your `VARCHAR` values to `TIME` and then use the following calculation which takes the difference in seconds (your lowest unit of interest one assumes) and creates a new `TIME` result.

```
DECLARE @total_work_time TIME = '07:15:00', @total_exeption_time TIME = '01:15:00';

SELECT CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @total_exeption_time, @total_work_time), '00:00'));
```